# Hooking into drupal's password mechanism

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, mybb

I'm converting a site from a forum system (mybb) into a drupal site and obviously the password schemes are completely different.

I'm planning on importing all of the users with their old password hashes prefixed with "mybb_".

I'd like to write a module which detects prefixed passwords if the user logs in authenticates using the old mechanism and then replaces the password with a drupal 7 hashed password.

I'm relatively new to drupal development so I'm not familiar enough with the hooks, etc needed to do this.

Any guidance would be great :)

(Also if there is a better way of dealing with this than I have proposed, please feel free to chime in.)

Comment: Drupal 7 has SHA with salt, and which hashing mybb has ?

Comment: @AyeshK It uses the following scheme:

`$user['password'] = md5( md5( $user['salt'] ) . md5( $input['password'] ) );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drupal does similar checks in the function [user_check_password()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!password.inc/function/user_check_password/7). It is called by the validation function [user_login_authenticate_validate()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_login_authenticate_validate/7) so you could override this using [hook_form_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) and point to a custom version of user_check_password() that includes your mybb check.

Another way, instead of overriding, just add a validation handler in the login form before the default ones and detect, authenticate, and rehash the password there.

Comment: I had found a way to override, how do you go about just adding an extra function before the regular ones?

Comment: use hook_form_alter() on form user_login(). The user_login form uses user_login_default_validators() function to add the validation handlers so just change this so it invokes your custom one before those. http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_login_default_validators/7 Note: you will have to do the same for the user_login_block() if you are using that too.